# get properties from an List Item

Tags: javascript, office-365, client-object-model

I'm following a [code sample from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj163201%28v=office.15%29) to get properties of items from a list. My announcements list has 2 items. But for some reason I get an exception while getting the enumerator (`TypeError: collListItem.getEnumerator is not a function var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();`).
Any Idea why this might be happening?

```
function retrieveListItemsInclude() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
    var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(
        collListItem,
        'Include(Id, DisplayName, HasUniqueRoleAssignments)'
    );
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function onQuerySucceeded(collListItem) {
        var listItemInfo = '';
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +
                '\nDisplay name: ' + oListItem.get_displayName() +
                '\nUnique role assignments: ' +
                oListItem.get_hasUniqueRoleAssignments();
        }

        alert(listItemInfo.toString());
    }, function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it's the same as your code, but moved the success/fail handlers outside as functions:

```
var collListItem;

function retrieveListItemsInclude() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
    collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(
        collListItem,
        'Include(Id, DisplayName, HasUniqueRoleAssignments)'
    );
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +
            '\nDisplay name: ' + oListItem.get_displayName() +
            '\nUnique role assignments: ' +
            oListItem.get_hasUniqueRoleAssignments();
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: This should solve your problem.  Gotta watch your nested constructors.